# Who appends Unix Epoch timestamps to Firefox profile names?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

When Firefox first runs in Mac OS X, by default it creates a user profile folder named…

```
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default
```

where xxxxxxx is random ASCII characters.

Some of my app's users have recently discovered that their profile folders have had what is apparently a Unix Epoch Timestamp in milliseconds appended to their profile folder name, so it becomes, for example…

```
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default-1352077074018
```

I realize that a power user can edit Firefox profile names, but these users say they didn't do it.  Does anyone know what software would do that to a Firefox profile and why?  I presume it was done either by Firefox itself or maybe a Firefox extension.

(I support an app which interacts with Firefox, this makes it difficult for my app to keep track of that profile.)

Comment: A likely possibility is the [Reset Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems) feature. Please see [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=717070) regarding the timestamp format. Depending on the platform and Firefox version, there are at least two/three triggers for the reset, according to the [Moz wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Support/Firefox_Features/Clean_up_user_profile/TestPlan).

Comment: Thank you, vWil.  You are apparently correct.  Click in Firefox menu: Help > Troubleshooting Information.  Then click the "Reset Firefox" button, OK to go ahead, and a new profile named default-<Unix Epoch Timestamp> is created.